# What is the significance of adding Google Play services to android project for push notification?

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, ibm-mobilefirst

I have upgrade my worklight project from worklight 6.1 to mobilefirst 7.1. In previous project (WL6.1), pushnotification is working fine.

For mobilefirst, While checking ibm tutorials, I found this link for Adding Google Play services to your Android project.

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_adding_google_play_services.html

For pushnotification, is this step required? As per link, it will increase my application size. What is the significance of assming Google Service library? Can I skip it?

After configuring android pushnotification in mobilefirst 7.1 (Except adding goole service), I am facing this error on server side

```
com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.gcm.GCMMediator addTokenToAndroidKey FPWSE1079W: GCM push token '@@TOKEN_ID@@' is not added to GCM notification key. GCM Service invocation failed (reason: Error while invoking request)
                                     com.ibm.pushworks.server.exceptions.GCMException: GCM Service invocation failed (reason: Error while invoking request)
        at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.gcm.GCMSender.sendToGCM(GCMSender.java:392)
        at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.gcm.GCMSender.addTokenToAndroidKey(GCMSender.java:364)
        at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.gcm.GCMMediator.addTokenToAndroidKey(GCMMediator.java:206)
        at com.ibm.pushworks.server.core.PushServiceImpl.getNotificationKey(PushServiceImpl.java:2160)
        at com.ibm.pushworks.server.core.PushServiceImpl.registerDevice(PushServiceImpl.java:613)
        at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.updateDeviceToken(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:473)
        ......

    Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to android.googleapis.com:443 [android.googleapis.com/216.58.210.202, android.googleapis.com/216.58.210.234] failed: Connection refused: connect
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:319)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
        at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.gcm.GCMSender.sendToGCM(GCMSender.java:388)
        ... 45 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:412)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:271)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:258)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:376)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:244)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:125)
        ... 56 more
```

Can this be GCM port opening issue or relevant to google play services?

Comment: Is this a native or hybrid application?

Comment: it's a hybrid application

Answer (score 1):

Google has deprecated the use of GCM.jar in a project and from its perspective you should use the Google Play Services library.

For IBM MobileFirst Platform, though, the Google Play Services library is required if you need to use the Cloud Sync feature and others (by Google). If you don't need this feature don't add the library, as there is still a built-in implementation in the MobileFirst SDK for push notifications using GCM.jar.

Notes:

1. Starting MobileFirst Foundation 8.0, the library is now required.
2. In v7.1, you can still use the library regardless of the built-in fallback, but you will need to use Android's ProGuard feature to decrease the classes size to prevent the dex error ("too many classes") and in general to reduce to size.

As for the network error, it seems that your network configuration is lacking (connection refused). The documentation also lists addresses/ports that Google requires having them open/accessible to properly function.